# Does boost::bind cause overhead?

Tags: c++, boost, bind, overhead

I am currently working on network software. It has one main class, `server` which obviously represents a server instance.

A `server` instance can send requests and the user is notified of the response by a callback.

The code is like:

```
class server
{
  public:
    typedef boost::function<void (int duration)> callback_func;

    void send_request(endpoint& ep, callback_func cb);
};
```

Now let's say that, as a user I want to the callback to know about the instance that called it, I can do the following thing:

```
void mycallback(const server& sv, int duration) { ... }

server sv;
sv.send_request("localhost", boost::bind(&mycallback, boost::ref(sv), _1));
```

But I wonder: is there any overhead doing so ? Will the calls to `mycallback` be any slower than using a "regular" call ?

Thank you.

*Foot note: I could of course change my `typedef` to: `typedef boost::function<void (const server& sv, int duration)> callback_func;` and if `boost::bind` cause any significant overhead, that's probably what I will do in the end. I would just like to know what costs implies the use of `boost::bind`.*

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Of course it causes overhead. What it does is that it creates a functor that stores the bound parameters and has an `operator()` that you call with the remaining arguments. Now, is this significant? I don't know, because that is just a word. Make 10 million requests and measure it. You are the only one who can tell if this overhead is significant to you or not.

Also, I faced a similar problem. Since I didn't really need delegates, I could get away with function pointers. But I found an interesting [benchmark](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cpp/fastdelegate2.aspx) which also mentions some alternative implementation, all of them with better performance than `boost::function`. This comes at the cost of portability and in some cases ugly, non-standard hacks in the implementation (but a really good performance in return).

Comment: Boost v1.36.0 (released in 2008) introduced a small object optimisation for `boost::function` that renders the results of the referenced benchmark (from 2007) invalid.

Comment: That's an important note, thank you. Do you know about a more recent benchmark by any chance?

Answer (score 5):

`boost::bind` generates a functional object which can be optimized out if it is used as argument to function templates, but `boost::function` prevents this optimization, just like passing a pointer to a function will prevent its inlining. `boost::function` itself need not introduce more overhead than a virtual function all or call via a pointer to function.

PS. I agree with Tamás Szelei: make 10 million requests and measure it.

Comment: Even if passed as an argument to a template function, it depends on your compiler: the other day I was testing a straight loop with iterators vs std::for_each with boost::bind: gcc 4.5 optimized it to almost the same code, with gcc 4.1 and 4.2 it produced sizable bloat.

Comment: boost::function<> uses heap allocation for objects not very small. So you better check whether your bind objects are below the limit.

Answer (score 2):

Compared to a normal function call, you're paying for *two* indirections for the function call, which is similar to the overhead of a (non-devirtualised) virtual function call.

The first indirection is due to the type erasure that happens in boost::function (this is [documented](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_46_1/doc/html/function/misc.html#id1295842) in the `boost::function` documentation). This one cannot really be optimized, and you'd have the same penalty with a naked function pointer, too.

The second indirection comes from calling the `mycallback` function through a function pointer. A very well-optimising compiler can figure this out and optimise this out, but a normal compiler won't. You can get rid of this indirection (in all compilers) if you turn `mycallback` into a function object:

Instead of

```
void mycallback( .1. ) { .2. }
```

you do

```
struct mycallback {
    void operator()( .1. ) const { .2. }
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Be aware that boost::bind causes a *copy* of the functor. This can be very significant. For my operating system news and deletes are very expensive. See boost::bind documentation about ref() and cref(). I believe that member functions also cause functor copies but there is no documentation about that.

Comment: I was wrong. boost::bind does **not** make a copy of the functor but it does make a copy of parameters. See boost::bind documentation about ref() and cref() for versions that do not copy parameters.