# Does boost::io_service post method cause a new allocation?

Tags: c++, performance, boost, boost-asio

I'm doing asynchronous processing of events using `boost::io_service` via the `post()` method with a `boost::bind` object. Does anyone know if this causes a new allocation? I know there is an event queue underneath but I'm know sure how it works fully. Obviously I'm concerned about high-performance.

Comment: have you profiled your application?

Comment: Yes. I'm trying to avoid new allocations on the critical path.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, it causes an allocation. In case the allocation is a performance problem, you can use a [custom allocator for the handler](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/doc/html/boost_asio/example/allocation/server.cpp).

Comment: I tested it myself with an override for global new. It seems 3 allocations actually occur during boost::io_service post. Even with the custom allocator for the handler it still does 2 allocations.

Comment: The allocations could be from [boost::bind](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5894956/does-boostbind-cause-overhead). If you are trying to keep the asio overhead low, maybe it would be worth to have a look at the examples of [Marat Abrarov](http://sourceforge.net/projects/asio-samples). They show some [patterns](http://article.gmane.org/gmane.comp.lib.boost.asio.user/5512) for high performance asio usage that are not in the official asio examples.